# How to deal with python import with custom API

Tags: python, api, python-3.x

I created an API for my work. 
(python version 3.4)
My API look like this:

- MyAPI

  - `__init_.py`
- Communication

  - `__init_.py`
  - `SerialCom.py`
- JsonManager

  - `__init__.py`
  - `VersionHandler.py`
- Sessions

  - `__init__.py`
  - `SessionManager.py`
  - `Session.py`
- TestAPI

  - `__init__.py`
  - `mainWindows.py`
  - `mainWindowsQtUi.py`

In my testAPI it work well I have to problem with import importing my API this way:

```
from Sessions.SessionManager import SessionManager
```

But when I try to import it in another project I got some trouble with import.
I'm using Visual studio with Python plug-in
I added my API in the search paths it look like that:

```
My_api/MyAPI
      /MyAPI_Test
```

so in my code I try this :

```
from My_api.MyAPI.Sessions.SessionManager import SessionManager
```

And I got an `ImportError`. Visual studio show me the `SessionManager` file in the API
and show me this line:

```
from Sessions.Session import Session
```

I'm confused, it works fine with my TestAPI package but fail with an external package. I guess I missed something but don't know what.

Comment: Did you put a  `__init__.py` file in each directory or do some of the directories have  an `init.py` file instead?

Comment: In each directory including the main folder

Comment: Try putting `My_api/MyAPI` in `PYTHONPATH` env variable and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ensure, that your project directory exists in PYTHONPATH.

If that is not the case,
This could occur if you are already importing `SessionManager` in your Sessions/**init**.py. Then when you try -

```
from Sessions.SessionManager import SessionManager
```

python is trying to import SessionManager from SessionManager class.

Comment: All my init files are empty, i import nothing

Comment: Ensure that your project directory exists in PYTHONPATH